# How do I write an || expression in Javascript where 0 isn't treated as a falsy value?

Tags: javascript

Please forgive my English. I am not a native speaker.

My problem comes when I write code like this

```
luminosity = settings.luminosity || 50;
opacity = settings.opacity || 100;
```

The problem is that `0` is supposed to be a valid value, but it will be overlook because `0` is falsy in Javascript and it will set to the default value on the right of `||`.

Is there a way to do a fix so `0` isn't treated as falsy?

Right now I am doing

```
luminosity = "luminosity" in settings ? settings.luminosity : 50;
```

but I don't like that because it is so long.

Comment: I don't think you can write it any shorter than that. Besides, your approach is well readable, so I wouldn't even try to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is write a helper function...

```
function ifNotSet(val, other) {
    return typeof val === "undefined" ? other : val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to string `'0'` is `truthy`:

```
luminosity = settings.luminosity === 0 ? '' + settings.luminosity : settings.luminosity || 50;
opacity = settings.opacity === 0 ? '' + settings.opacity : settings.opacity || 100;
```

Or you can simply use this depending on your input or requirement:

```
luminosity = '' + settings.luminosity || 50;
opacity = '' + settings.opacity || 100;
```

`'' + number` is shorthand for converting a number to string.

Comment: `''+undefined` is `"undefined"`, so this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

A common way to have default option/settings is [`.extend()` method in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). Pure JS has this method too but with some different.

```
/* merge object2 into object1 */
$.extend(object1, object2);
```

**This is what you need:**

```
var defaultSetting = {luminosity : 50, opacity : 100};
setting = $.extend({}, defaultSetting, setting);
```

Comment: I believe it should be: `setting = $.extend({}, defaultSetting, setting);`. In the answer posted above, the properties in defaultSetting overwrite those in setting, even if the properties in setting are already defined.

Comment: There's no mention of jQuery in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the initial version of @Tooraj's code:

```
var setting = {luminosity:0};
var defaultSetting = {luminosity:50, opacity:100};

setting = $.extend({}, defaultSetting, setting);

// setting now has a value of {luminosity:0, opacity:100}
```

I haven't done this before. But it seems to work fine in FF, Chrome, and IE9.